# Talend importing library

Tags: java, json, talend

I am using Talend 6.2.1 and i have downloaded the json-schema-validation.zip, tried importing it under Window->Preferences->Java->Build Path->User Libraries, but this does not seem to give me access to the library.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to Use the tLibraryLoad component to load a lib file in a job.

[image]

Here you can easily load external library from your local file system..